# Why would the number of pages that Google is indexing fluctuate wildly?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-index

The number of pages Google is indexing looks like this:

[image]

We have 12,000 pages total.  Is there any explanation as to why google is doing this?

it's very unsatisfying because if the index is up, we actually see more visitors, and if down, we get a lot fewer visitors and sales.

Comment: There isn't enough information to go off just from this report. Are you getting crawl errors? Are all 12K pages unique? All in your sitemap(s)? Do you use query parameters for your pages?

Comment: @tshimkus its a wholesaler page, that means that on the page items are sold that are available in other places of the internet as well. So the pages are not unique on the internet, at least, most information is not, as it is product codes, price product description etc.there is a sitemap and most urls of the sitemap are not indexed. Almost no crawl errors. Almost never query parameters

Comment: My question about the pages being unique was specific to your site. Making sure each page has its own URL, title, meta description, and content. Besides sitemaps is there a good way for your pages to be discovered by bots? Do you have a robust internal linking structure that would allow the bots to reach every page?

Comment: @tshimkus hmm yes, basically once you reach the page, it lists _all_ products via pagination. As well: I can see in google search console that google _knows_ about the page. But the pages are not indexed in the public index on purpose. The url title and meta description are generated from each product

Comment: You can see more details of indexing in the new coverage report. Submitting sitemaps can also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> its a wholesaler page

This would be for me an explaination for such ups and downs.

Firstly, not all items are unique - so Google needs time to get this.

Secondly, i suppose, that you have a high volaitility on your site - means, products are published and sold out very fast.

Indexing is a sluggish process - it happens very often, that just after your product was indexed, is it already sold out and Google tries to get the up-to-date status through deindexing of soldout products again.

This setup is nothing dangerous. But it isn't optimal regarding of usage of Google's ressources. Try to index only those products, which are always on sale. Another good way could be to index product categories.